# asp.net FileUpload control restrict files by extension

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax, file-upload

I have a following behind code for a fileupload witch is limited to upload only "PNG" files. How I can do to allow also "JPG" and "JPEG" files to upload?

```
protected void btnMainPicUPL_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        String ext = System.IO.Path.GetExtension(fulMainPicUPL.FileName);

        if (ext == ".png")
        {
            String path = Server.MapPath("\\~/../Logged_in/AdminFotoUser/UserPics\\");
            fulMainPicUPL.SaveAs(path + txtMainPicUPL.Text + ext);
        }

        else
        {
            lblServerMSG.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
            lblServerMSG.Text = "<br>No hemos podido cargar tu foto!";
        }
    }
```

Comment: Have you tried just adding jpg and jpeg to your if statement?
if (ext == ".png" || ext == ".jpg" || ext == ".jpeg")

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could store your allowed file extensions in an array, then do a Contains on it like this:

```
        string ext = System.IO.Path.GetExtension(fulMainPicUPL.FileName);

        string[] allowedExtenstions = new string[] { ".png", ".jpg", ".jpeg" };

        if (allowedExtenstions.Contains(ext))
        {
        string path = Server.MapPath("\\~/../Logged_in/AdminFotoUser/UserPics\\");
        fulMainPicUPL.SaveAs(path + txtMainPicUPL.Text + ext);
        }
```

Please note, you would be better off storing the allowed file extensions in a configurable place like the in your `appSettings`.